# Non recursive floor method for Binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to get this to work but while it works for majority of the input sometimes it gives the wrong output. I have spent some time debugging the code and it seems the problem is when i get a Node that is smaller than the root but bigger than the left node under the root.

How can I traverse the right sub-tree and still return the right key if no node in the right sub-tree is the floor node for that key?

Comment: I don't get it what is this algorithm supposed to do ?

Comment: It should be a non-recursive implementation of the floor() operation on BSTs.

Comment: so you want to get the node with the biggest key <= key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if you do anything recursively, it can be transformed* into iteration.

Let's consider taking the floor of a well-formed BST, which should simply be the smallest element which is less than or equal to your key in the tree.  All we have to do is traverse the tree to get it.

Let's implement it recursively so we can tease out a few important corollaries between iteration and recursion.

```
// Assuming non-null root node with method declaration
private Node floor(Node root, Key key, Node lowestNode) {
    if(key.compareTo(root.getKey()) <= 0) {
        if(root.getLeft() != null) {
            return floor(root.getLeft(), key, lowestNode);
        } else {
            return root.compareTo(lowestNode) < 0 ? root : lowestNode;
        }
     } else {
        if(root.getRight() != null) {
           lowestRightNode.add(root);
           return floor(root.getRight(), key, lowestNode);
        } else {
           return lowestNode;
     }
}
```

Let's walk through the conditions for success.

- If we compare a node to be less than or equal to our key value:

  - If we have a left child, there's something smaller.  Traverse down the left half of the tree.
  - Otherwise, we're at the floor - which means we're at the node whose value is less than or equal to our key.  Return it.
- Otherwise (our node has a value greater than our key):

  - If we have a right child, there's a chance that our work isn't done yet (something's smaller).  We'd like to keep it around since we could step off of the tree, so let's store it, then traverse down the right half of the tree.
  - Otherwise, we've fallen off of the tree.  Return the smallest element we've kept track of.

An example may look something like this:

```
        9
       / \
      3  14
     / \  
    1  2
```

With a key of 12:

- Compare with 9.  We're larger.  Store 9 in our lowest node variable, recurse right.
- Compare with 14.  We're smaller, but we don't have a left child.  We compare the value 14 to 9 and 9 is smaller, so we return the node with 9.

If we want to convert this into iteration, then think about your starting point, your conditional check, and your incrementation steps.

- Starting point:  A non-null node
- Conditional check:

  - `key.compareTo(root.getKey()) <= 0`

    - `root.getLeft() != null`

      - continue
    - `root.compareTo(lowestRightNode) < 0 ? root : lowestRightNode`

      - terminal
  - else

    - `root.getRight() != null`

      - store temp value and continue
    - `return lowestRightNode`

      - terminal

Pay close attention to your continuation conditions, and what other work you'd have to do to keep track of the lowest node you've seen so far (only for the right-hand side, that is).

<sup>*:  Some recursive operations are more *painful* to convert than others, of course.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation. I figured it out but this helps me understand this better.